# Physics with an object made of several parts

Tags: physics

I am trying to throw a die made of several parts that must stay fixed. The purpose is to get a realistic physical behavior.

What I tried :
The small parts have an object constraint : Child of set to the biggest part.
Their rigid bodies are set as passive. The parts are not overlapping.

What I get :
The die jumps at the beginning of the animation ... as if a collision was  detected ...

Thank you to suggest a way to do this ... even if it is radically different from what I tried.  :)

Thanks

![die]https://ibb.co/Twyzj6v

Comment: How does your setup differ from throwing a normal die and parenting the different parts to the box collider?

Comment: A screenshot of the die setup would be useful to understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: @Sazerac      https://ibb.co/0yVqRjC   ...   (tell me if there is a better way to show an image in comments)   I made this image in Photoshop to show the settings of Dé (the die ... which is not a cube as you see) and Vitre (one of the small parts

Comment: Edit your post and include the image.

Answer (score 1):

create a cube the size of the die, make the cube not rendered and then use it as a rigid body physics and parent the die pieces to it

Comment: Thanks, but won't Blender use the envelope of the cube to calculate the physics ?